# Click through a 'hole' cut with mix-blend-mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mix-blend-mode

This looks like it should be possible, but the solution has eluded me for too long.   Can you make a link clickable in a background revealed through a hole cut in a scrollable div using mix-blend-mode?  I've tried the usual trick of `pointer-events:none`, but this doesn't work because the 'hole' is not really transparent, and probably also because the background is actually two levels down.

Here's my code so far:

```html
<div style="height:400px;width:300px;margin:0 auto;background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0px,#ebebeb 60px);border:1px solid grey;overflow:scroll;position:relative;">
  <div style="padding:20px"><span>
        lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor 
      </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:white;mix-blend-mode:hard-light;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;overflow:scroll">
    <div style="height:300px"></div>
    <div style="width: 90%;height: 50px;margin: 0 auto 0;border: solid 1px red;border-radius: 10px;background:grey;pointer-events:none;"></div>
    <div style="height:2000px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you scroll the content, you will see the background content come in to view - with a link - but I can't work out how to make the link clickable (if it's possible).

Thanks for any suggestions.  A JS/Jquery solution would be fine, though straight CSS is the first preference.

Comment: Even with JS/JQuery...actually, if you have one link -> not too much work: https://jsfiddle.net/ay3q5dw9/ Because, link position(s) will be always 'static' (relative to link parent), and you can add more links and just calculate 'mask' position and compare it with links position...

Answer (score 1):

> The mix-blend-mode CSS property describes how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's direct parent and the element's background.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Blending modes simply provide visual ways to mix layer colors, but the DOM is still the same. So in the way you are approaching it right now there is no possibility of clicking through that visual "hole".

You would need to use JavaScript to actually trigger a click in a link behind an element.

Using CSS, I found there is an option to click through. You can make use of **pointer-events: none; this could make the link behind clickable. However, it would make the element not respond to any mouse event including scroll**.

```css
#a{pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<div style="height:400px;width:300px;margin:0 auto;background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0px,#ebebeb 60px);border:1px solid grey;overflow:scroll;position:relative;">
  <div style="padding:20px"><span>
        lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor 
      </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com>Stack Overflow">Stack Overflow</a>
  </div>
  <div id="a" style="height:100%;width:100%;background:white;mix-blend-mode:hard-light;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;overflow:scroll">
    <div style="height:300px"></div>
    <div style="width: 90%;height: 50px;margin: 0 auto 0;border: solid 1px red;border-radius: 10px;background:grey;pointer-events:none;"></div>
    <div style="height:2000px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's the point I got to as well - I need the top divs to be able to scroll and to have clickable elements.  The aim is to be able to click on a background element when it is visible in the 'hole' without affecting any actions on the top layers.  If the background link is in a fixed position in the viewport, I could get the position of the hole and trigger a click via JS, but that seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this here as a solution to my own needs (and very much in line with the solution proposed simultaneously by @sinisake above) - but I'd still be interested in a more generic solution.

(The click function is commented out because the sandbox won't allow `window.open`.)

```js
$('#overlay').click(function() {
  alert('visible')
  if ($(this).offset().top < 230 && $(this).offset().top > 180) {
    //window.open($('#link').attr('href'), '_blank');
    alert($('#link').attr('href'), '_blank');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="back" style="height:400px;width:300px;margin:0 auto;background:lightblue;background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0px,#ebebeb 60px);border:1px solid grey;overflow:scroll;position:relative;">
  <div style="padding:20px"><span>
        lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor 
      </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="link" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:white;mix-blend-mode:hard-light;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;overflow:scroll;">
    <div style="height:300px"></div>
    <div id="overlay" style="width: 90%;height: 50px;margin: 0 auto 0;border: solid 1px red;border-radius: 10px;background:grey"></div>
    <div style="height:2000px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
$('#overlay').click(function(e) { 
  if(isElement($("a"),e)){
     console.log("link clicked");
  } 
});

function isElement($el, e){
  var xmin = $el.offset().left;
  var ymin = $el.offset().top;
  var xmax = xmin +  $el.width();
  var ymax = ymin + $el.height();
  
  if(e.pageX >= xmin && e.pageX <= xmax &&  e.pageY >= ymin && ymax >= e.pageY){
   return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="back" style="height:400px;width:300px;margin:0 auto;background:lightblue;background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0px,#ebebeb 60px);border:1px solid grey;overflow:scroll;position:relative;">
  <div style="padding:20px"><span>
        lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor lorem ipsum amet sit dolor 
      </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="link" style="background-color:yellow;" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:white;mix-blend-mode:hard-light;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;overflow:scroll;">
    <div style="height:300px"></div>
    <div id="overlay" style="width: 90%;height: 50px;margin: 0 auto 0;border: solid 1px red;border-radius: 10px;background:grey"></div>
    <div style="height:2000px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```